# AppWidget does not finish updating when adding it for the first time

Tags: android, android-intent, appwidgetprovider, android-appwidget

**Edit: I installed my app 4.x devices and there is no problem. Problem exists only with 3.x devices.**

I am trying to update an AppWidget manually when a user setting 
changes on the device. To do so I use code similar to this:

```
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, MyAppWidget.class); 
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this); 
manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
```

I can tell that my AppWidget onUpdate method is being called as a 
result since I log some debug strings to logcat in the code. However 
the AppWidget itself doesn't change on the screen.

Here comes the interesting part: if I rotate my device and force a 
refresh of the home screen (from PORTRAIT to LANDSCAPE or vice-versa) 
then finally my AppWidget gets updated. However rotating the device 
does not trigger the onUpdate method to be called, so the AppWidget 
must be using the RemoteViews provided in the earlier update.

Can somebody explain me what to do to force the home screen redraw of 
my AppWidget when it processes an update?

I am using `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />`

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
  int[] appWidgetIds) {

  // Get all ids
  ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyProvider.class);
  int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
  // Build the intent to call the service
  Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
  intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.appwidget_layout);

  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

  // Update the widgets via the service
  context.startService(intent);
}
```

And my service:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i(LOG, "Called");

    this.appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

    this.allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    Log.w(LOG, "From Intent" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds.length));        
    Log.w(LOG, "Direct" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds2.length));
    config = getResources().getConfiguration();

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        //do things like starting ASYNCs (couple of them) to fetch data from server
        //and set an adapter for the gridview
    }   

    Intent intentOpen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainFragmentActivity.class);
    PendingIntent open = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intentOpen, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_whole, open);
    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widgetProgress, View.GONE);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( thisWidget, remoteViews );    
    Log.d(LOG, "sent!!");       
}
stopSelf();

super.onStart(intent, startId); }
```

Comment: Can you put a bit more code, maybe your onUpdate function?

Comment: Write log after every line, so you can track where it stops. I know that onReceive runs only 4 seconds, maybe something similar with onUpdate also

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="16" /> right click on project , properties , android version > 16

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in the launcher app to me. Every time you call `updateAppWidget` the ***AppWidgetManager*** receives the new layout and the launcher is responsible for redrawing the widget with this new layout.

The fact that when the screen is rotated `onUpdate` and `updateAppWidget` are not called, but the launcher redraws the widget with its new layout means that the ***AppWidgetManager*** has already successfully received that new layout.

When the screen is rotated the launcher is forced to redraw everything (its Activity is recreated) and that is why it shows the new layout.

And this bug is probably fixed in Android 4.0+

Answer (score -1):

I would try calling `invalidate()` on the Views in your widget. Calling that forces the system to redraw the View.

Comment: RemoteViews does not have `invalidate` method.

Comment: Oops, `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` in AppWidgetManager might do the trick. It tells the corresponding view to invalidate its data.

Comment: nope no luck with that. I am already using `updateAppWidget` function. I tried `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` nothing changed.